# glClear() gives GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY on Intel HD 4000 (GL 4.0) but not GeForce (GL 4.2)... why?

Tags: opengl, go, framebuffer, render-to-texture

Now, this is an extremely odd behavior.

TL;DR -- in a render-to-texture setup, upon resizing the window (framebuffer 0) only the very next call to **glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)** for bound framebuffer 0 (the window's client area) gives **GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY**, only on one of two GPUs, however rendering still proceeds properly and correctly.

Now, all the gritty details:

So this is on a Vaio Z with two GPUs (that can be switched-to with a physical toggle button on the machine):

1. OpenGL 4.2.0 @ NVIDIA Corporation GeForce GT 640M LE/PCIe/SSE2 (GLSL: 4.20 NVIDIA via Cg compiler)
2. OpenGL 4.0.0 - Build 9.17.10.2867 @ Intel Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (GLSL: 4.00 - Build 9.17.10.2867)

My program is in Go 1.0.3 64-bit under Win 7 64-bit using GLFW 64-bit.

I have a fairly simple and straightforward render-to-texture "mini pipeline". First, normal 3D geometry is rendered with the simplest of shaders (no lighting, nothing, just textured triangle meshes which are just a number of cubes and planes) to a framebuffer that has both a depth/stencil renderbuffer as depth/stencil attachment and a texture2D as color attachment. For the texture all filtering is disabled as are mip-maps.

Then I render a full-screen quad (a single "oversized" full-screen tri actually) just sampling from said framebuffer texture (color attachment) with texelFetch(tex, gl_FragCoord.xy, 0) so no wrapping is used.

Both GPUs render this just fine, both when I force a core profile and when I don't. No GL errors are ever reported for this, all renders as expected too. Except when I resize the window while using the Intel HD 4000 GPU's GL 4.0 renderer (both in Core profile and Comp profile). Only in that case, a single resize will record a GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error directly after the very next glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) call on framebuffer 0 (the screen), but only once after the resize, not in every subsequent loop iteration.

**Interestingly, I don't even actually do any allocations on resize!** I have temporarily disabled ALL logic occuring on window resize -- that is, right now I simply fully *ignore* the window-resize event, meaning the RTT framebuffer and its depth and color attachment resolutions are not even changed/recreated. Meaning the next glViewPort will still use the same dimensions as when the window and GL context was first created, but anyhoo the error occurs on glClear() (not before, only after, only once -- I've double- and triple-checked).

Would this be a driver bug, or is there anything I could be doing wrongly here?

Comment: Are you checking errors after every OpenGL call?  `glGetError` only holds onto the first error a program causes, so to really know where the error's coming from, you need to check after every OpenGL call.  Try that to see if you can narrow down the range.

Comment: Yes I did, I can confirm this only occurred right after the first glClear(framebuf0) and not before and no other errors either, by temporarily having checked for errors in between all rendering steps...

Comment: An OpenGL implementation can throw that memory error at any time, so it will be difficult to say what the problem is exactly. Only advice I can give is try using smaller textures to try to reduce the memory usage.

Comment: Na, this example was just using 2 rgba textures of 512x512. I'll file it as Intel HD 4000 driver bug for now. The GeForce has 2GB VRAM but how much the HD has/uses, no idea...

Comment: "Intel" plus "OpenGL" plus "strange problem" is sadly almost self-explanatory. Though execution of _any command_ may in principle give `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` (this is the only error that can occur even when not specified) it's not conceivable how clearing a framebuffer could possibly result in that kind of error (no matter how big or small a buffer is or what format it has). After you've successcully bound a framebuffer and satisfied attachments, all memory needed is already allocated.

Comment: Also, Intel HD 4000 doesn't have any such thing as dedicated VRAM, it uses main memory. So if you see an out of memory condition, _and it's not total bullshit_, then it consequently means you've got insufficient physical RAM and/or swap space. That's ... rather... unlikely to be the case.

Comment: Yeah I'm quite sure I wasn't maxing out my 12GB RAM... as posted below, a glitch resulting from depth-bits being set to 0 for the "screen"/window/main-default-framebuffer-0... depth-bits of 8 instead resolve that glitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting glitch in the HD's GL driver, it seems:

When I switched to the render-to-texture setup, I also set the depth/stencil bits at GL context creation for the primary framebuffer 0 (ie. the screen/window) both to 0. This is when I started seeing this error and framerate became quite sluggish compared to before.

I experimentally set the (strictly speaking unneeded) depth-bits to 8 and both of these issues are gone. So seems like the current HD 4000 GL 4.0 driver version just doesn't like a value of 0 for its depth buffer bits at GL context creation.